# Переведите новый интерфейс тревог для комментариев

Tags: дефект, статус-завершено, локализация, тревоги

Новый интерфейс тревог наполовину не переведён

[image: Скрин тревоги для комментариев]

Думаю, как и что переводить, очевидно.

Comment: А за что минусанули-то?

Comment: @alexolut Наверное, считают, что не надо переводить:)

Comment: Или за то, что чат не читаете :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Уже переведено.](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/22462?m=38815436#38815436) Надо только дождаться более свежей сборки. > 2017.7.14.1282.